# Differences between SSRS 2005 and 2008

Tags: reportingservices-2005

What the main differences between SQL Reporting Services 2005 and 2008 in terms of features? I read about 2008 has much better in scalability. How about the features? What's in SSRS 2008 but not 2005? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Granted, I'm researching the answers to the same question, but what I've learned thus far:
2005 has the Table if you know the number of columns but a variable number of rows.  2005 has the Matrix if you will have a variable number of columns AND rows

2008 has a control called the "tablix" which appears to have the properties of both the 2005 table and matrix controls.

Other than that 1 main difference, I've only seen marketing buzzwords.

Good luck!

Comment: This guy has some additions: http://mattclingan.wordpress.com/2008/05/01/new-features-of-ssrs-2008/

Answer (score 1):

I've just started this process, and one of the biggest issues I've found so far is the inability to authenticate non-domain users for the reports. SSRS 2008 doesn't use IIS as 2005 did.