# Differences between SQL Server Reporting Server SSRS 2005 / 2008 R2?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Had a search and only found [Differences between SSRS 2005 and 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325371/differences-between-ssrs-2005-and-2008) listing the "only" difference between 2005 and 2008 being the introduction of tablix (table + matrix) control.

Was there anything else? And what about 2008 -> 2008 R2?

Thanks

Comment: You can see the [differences here](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/versions/reporting-services/reporting-services-2008-r2.htm) (also the differences for [SSRS 2012](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/versions/reporting-services/reporting-services-2012.htm))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 significantly changes the report rendering engine and introduces an updated schema for the xml code of the reports. SQL 2008 R2 introduces some new controls like sparklines, etc. and improves the error information returned when there is a problem with a report. See [What's New (Reporting Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170438.aspx) for details on 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

The major difference in SSRS 2008 & 2008 R2 is 2008 R2 has a facility of shared data set.